# Is this optimization problem with integral domain and monotone functions tractable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, monotone-functions, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Let us consider a collection of monotone increasing functions $f_k: \mathbb{Z}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  For a fixed parameter $s$, the following problem

$$
\begin{aligned}
\underset{a}{\text{minimize}} \quad & \sum_{k = 1}^K f_k(a_k)\\
\textrm{subject to}
\quad & a_k \in \mathbb{Z}_+\\
\quad & \sum_{k = 1}^K a_k = s,
\end{aligned}
$$

can be solved by a greedy algorithm which sequentially assigns $a_{k^\star} \leftarrow a_{k^\star} + 1$ where $k^\star$ solves $\text{min}_k\ f_k(a_k + 1) - f_k(a_k)$.  This elegant solution results from the monotonicity and separability of the objective.

I am interested in how far this can be generalized, and especially in the case where the objective is a difference of monotone functions.  If we have function $f(x), h(x)$ with only the property that $x \le y \implies f(x) \le f(y)$ (with element-wise inequalities) then surely the problem with objective $f(x) - h(x)$ cannot be solved.  However, we can consider simpler generalizations, for example:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\underset{a}{\text{minimize}} \quad & \sum_{k = 1}^K f_k(a_k) + H(-\sum_{k = 1}^K h_k(a_k))\\
\textrm{subject to}
\quad & a_k \in \mathbb{Z}_+\\
\quad & \sum_{k = 1}^K a_k = s,
\end{aligned}
$$

where $f_k, H, h_k$ are all monotone increasing.  Would there be any hope in finding an efficient algorithm for such a problem?  Relying in some way again on the separability? I am familiar with work on similar problems in the continuous case (e.g. [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1052623499359828?journalCode=sjope8)) but have found no references dealing with this discrete version.  Are there any such papers?